# product image url not valid - magento 2.0.1

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, object-manager

I have **created a widget**. I am trying to **show product image in widget**. I have successfully got product name, product url and image url using object manager. But the **Image is not loaded** (404 - not found).

```
public function getCollection()
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $collection = $productCollection->create()->setPageSize(1)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->load();

    return $collection;
}

public function getPImage()
{
 $col=$this->getCollection();
 foreach ($col as $product)
 {
    echo $product->getImage();
 }  
}
```

getPImage() method returns string "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"

I use this string in img src

```
<img style="height:100%;width:100%;" src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg'); ?>" />
```

or without images prefix

```
<img style="height:100%;width:100%;" src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg'); ?>" />
```

Yet the image not found, broken image URL path. LumaChange is my custom theme.

```
http://magentodev.gworks.mobi/magento2/pub/static/frontend/LumaChange/Color/en_US/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg
```

when I found specific product by search store, image url look like below(valid)

```
http://magentodev.gworks.mobi/magento2/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/240x300/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg
```

Page widget div tag looks like below

[image: easy for your reference]

Any suggestion to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

try:

define image size in `app\design\frontend\MyPackage\mytheme\etc\view.xml` as

```
<image id="my_widget_image_size" type="small_image">
    <width>240</width>
    <height>360</height>
</image>
```

then your function:

```
public function getPImage()
    {
     $col=$this->getCollection();
     $image = 'my_widget_image_size';
     foreach ($col as $product)
     {
        $productImage = $block->getImage($product, $image);
        echo $productImage ->toHtml();
     }  
    }
```

This will give you the entire image HTML. So don't put this inside `img` `src`.

**Update: Get image url:**

If above method did not work for you try this one.

```
public function getPImage()
        {
         $col=$this->getCollection();
         $image = 'my_widget_image_size';
         foreach ($col as $product)
         {
            $productImage = $block->getImage($product, $image);
            $_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
            $productImage = $_imagehelper->init($product, $image)->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(400)->getUrl();
            echo $productImage;
         }  
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am working with your answer. after while come back to you

Comment: I try this, not work. it shows unrelevant error in page "_We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email._" . here $block refers what php class?

Comment: `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct`

Comment: I use this " **\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct::getImage($product, $image);  ** "  instead of "  ** $block->getImage($product, $image); **  " but still I get same error. Where could you refer this, please share the link if you have

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: again got same error "We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email."